# Method not found when setting proxy in HttpClientHandler Portable Class Library (PCL)

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, dotnet-httpclient, base-class-library

I'm using [Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries - PCL](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) (installed via NuGet) to communicate with a public REST API. Because I'm behind a corporate firewall, I need to configure the proxy info on the HttpClientHandler.

However, when setting proxy on the HttpClientHandler, it throws the following error:

> Method not found: 'Void System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_Proxy(System.Net.IWebProxy)'.

There's nothing special about my code, so I am a bit puzzled:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Proxy = new DefaultProxy
    {
        Credentials =
            new NetworkCredential(
                "firstname.lastname",
                "P4ssw0rd",
                "DOMAIN")
    },
    UseProxy = true
};

this.client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

**Some notes:**

- I've successfully used the HttpClientHandler from the standard .Net library (i.e. not PCL) for another project, so I know the proxy information is correct.
- I've successfully retrieved the data when the proxy is bypassed (i.e. outside the corporate network, or no proxy).
- DefaultProxy implements IWebProxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is due to the HttpClient package not being installed on the consuming project. You should be getting a warning similar:

All projects referencing [consuming project] must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Build.

Basically, every referencing a class library that references HttpClient & Async must also reference HttpClient & Async.

Comment: It's because of IWebProxy and the assembly it lives. We do some trickery so that it is seen as the same type on all the platforms - unless you install the package onto the consuming project, we don't know which binary to deploy and instead the one from the referenced project gets deployed, which leads to this error.